# Strings Became Symbols When They Output in C

Tags: c, string, data-structures, gets

I have a problem when i output some strings in my codes. When i input 1 string and then output it, there is no problem at all. But, when i input at least 2 strings, it went fail. The strings became symbols, except the last one. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I've been using fflush(stdin) and fflush(stdout), but the problem is still exist.
So, what should i do? I need your advice.

Here is my complete codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menu();
void entry();
void search();
void PrintSingle();
void PrintComplete();
float TotalUsed(int i);
float RegularCost(int i);
float tax(int i);
float discount(int i);
float TotalPayment(int i);

#define NMaks 101

typedef enum {false=0,true=1} boolean;
typedef struct {int BillNumber,BillClass;float LastMeter,CurrentMeter;char name[];} BillDatabase;
BillDatabase bill[NMaks];

int DataAmount=0;

int main() {

    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu() {

    int i;

    repeat:
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t.: Electric Billing System :.\n\n");
    printf("[1] Entries customer information\n");
    printf("[2] Search customer\n");
    printf("[3] Print single bill\n");
    printf("[4] Print complete billing report\n");
    printf("[5] Exit\n\n");
    printf("Select the menu[1..5]: ");scanf("%d",&i);

    switch (i) {
        case 1  :   entry();break;
        case 2  :   search();break;
        case 3  :   PrintSingle();break;
        case 4  :   PrintComplete();break;
        case 5  :   {
                    printf("\n\nGoodbye!");
                    getch();
                    break;
        }
        default :   {
                    printf("\n\nWrong menu!");
                    goto repeat;
        }
    }
}

void entry() {

    char repeat;

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t.: Electric Billing System :.\n\n");
        printf("[1] Entries customer information\n\n");
        DataAmount++;
        printf("Bill number: ");scanf("%d",&bill[DataAmount].BillNumber);
        printf("Customer name: ");fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);gets(bill[DataAmount].name);
        printf("Class[1..3]: ");scanf("%d",&bill[DataAmount].BillClass);
        printf("Last meter: ");scanf("%f",&bill[DataAmount].LastMeter);
        printf("Current meter: ");scanf("%f",&bill[DataAmount].CurrentMeter);
        printf("\nEntry again[y/n]: ");repeat=getche();
    } while (tolower(repeat)=='y');
    menu();
}

void search() {

    int i,BN;
    boolean found;
    char repeat;

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t.: Electric Billing System :.\n\n");
        printf("[2] Search customer\n\n");
        printf("Enter the bill number: ");scanf("%d",&BN);
        found=false;
        for (i=1;i<=DataAmount;i++)
            if (BN==bill[i].BillNumber) {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        if (found) {
            printf("\nCustomer found!\n\n");
            printf("Bill number\tN   a    m    e Class\t\tLast meter\tCurrent meter\n");
            fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);
            printf("%d\t\t%15.15s\t%d\t\t%.2f kWh\t%.2f kWh\n",bill[i].BillNumber,bill[i].name,bill[i].BillClass,bill[i].LastMeter,bill[i].CurrentMeter);
        }
        else
            printf("\nCustomer not found!\n");
        printf("\nSearch again[y/n]: ");repeat=getche();
    } while (tolower(repeat)=='y');
    menu();
}

void PrintSingle() {

    int i,BN;
    boolean found;
    char repeat;

    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t.: Electric Billing System :.\n\n");
        printf("[3] Print single bill\n\n");
        printf("Enter the bill number: ");scanf("%d",&BN);
        found=false;
        for (i=1;i<=DataAmount;i++)
            if (BN==bill[i].BillNumber) {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        if (found) {
            printf("\nCustomer found!\n\n");
            printf("Bill number\tN   a    m    e Class\t\tLast meter\tCurrent meter\n");
            fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);
            printf("%d\t\t%15.15s\t%d\t\t%.2f kWh\t%.2f kWh\n",bill[i].BillNumber,bill[i].name,bill[i].BillClass,bill[i].LastMeter,bill[i].CurrentMeter);
            printf("Total used\tRegular cost\tTax\t\tDiscount\tTotal Payment\n");
            printf("%.2f kWh\t$%7.2f\t$%7.2f\t$%7.2f\t$%7.2f\n",TotalUsed(i),RegularCost(i),tax(i),discount(i),TotalPayment(i));
        }
        else
            printf("\nCustomer not found!\n");
        printf("\nPrint again[y/n]: ");repeat=getche();
    } while (tolower(repeat)=='y');
    menu();
}

void PrintComplete() {

    int i;

    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t.: Electric Billing System :.\n\n");
    printf("[4] Print complete billing report\n\n");
    printf("Bill number\tN   a    m    e\t\tClass\tTotal Payment\n");
    for (i=1;i<=DataAmount;i++) {
        fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);
        printf("%d\t\t%15.15s\t\t%d\t$%.2f\n",bill[i].BillNumber,bill[i].name,bill[i].BillClass,TotalPayment(i));
    }
    printf("\nPress any key to the main menu");
    getch();
    menu();
}

float TotalUsed(int i) {

    return bill[i].CurrentMeter-bill[i].LastMeter;
}

float RegularCost(int i) {

    float price;

    switch (bill[i].BillClass) {
        case 1  :   price=10.0;break;
        case 2  :   price=7.5;break;
        default :   price=13.75;
    }
    return TotalUsed(i)*price;
}

float tax(int i) {

    float TaxPercentage;

    switch (bill[i].BillClass) {
        case 1  :   TaxPercentage=1.5/100;break;
        case 2  :   TaxPercentage=0.25/100;break;
        default :   TaxPercentage=3.5/100;
    }
    return RegularCost(i)-(RegularCost(i)*TaxPercentage);
}

float discount(int i) {

    float DiscountPercentage;

    switch (bill[i].BillClass) {
        case 1  :   DiscountPercentage=3.0/100;break;
        case 2  :   DiscountPercentage=2.0/100;break;
        default :   DiscountPercentage=5.5/100;break;
    }
    if (RegularCost(i)>100.0)
        return RegularCost(i)-(RegularCost(i)*DiscountPercentage);
    else
        return 0.0;
}

float TotalPayment(int i) {

    return RegularCost(i)+tax(i)-discount(i);
}
```

Note: I use Code Blocks for the IDE.

Comment: "I've been using `fflush(stdin)`" - *don't*; it isn't standard-compliant. And post your code *in your question*, reduced to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *reproduces* the problem.

Comment: Please provide higlight the part where the error shows up! its confusing!...

Comment: Thank you very much for the better screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

I see a number of problems here.

**First** of all, your over-use of global variables is troubling.  The array `bill` and the int `DataAmount` should **definitely** not be global.  This is not good c programming practice and I would not trust someone whose code looks like this.  Please give your "`menu`", "`entry`", "`printcomplete`", and "`search`" functions arguments so that you can make these variables local, not global.

**Second**, there are very few cases where it is acceptable to have many statements on the same line as in

```
 printf("Customer name: ");fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);gets(bill[DataAmount].name);
```

I'm getting a headache just looking at it!!! pleeease don't!

**Third**, You are not using array bounds correctly in this for loop, **which is the cause of the bug you are asking about in the first place.**

```
 for (i=1;i<=DataAmount;i++) {
    fflush(stdin);fflush(stdout);
    printf("%d\t\t%15.15s\t\t%d\t$%.2f\n",bill[i].BillNumber,bill[i].name,bill[i].BillClass,TotalPayment(i));
}
```

Remember, in the C language, array indices start at 0 and end at "n - 1".  Your loop is starting at 1 and ending at "n".

The reason for the bogus character is that you are accessing a `BillDataBase` that is outside the boundaries of the array `bill`.

**Fourth**, as Sami Kuhmonen said, you are not allocating any memory for your `name` array.  Although this is probably not causing the bug you are seeing, it will almost certainly cause your program to crash with a `segmentation fault` at some point in the future.  In order to fix this looming problem, you have 2 options

1. The easy way out: change your `BillDatabase` struct to the following

   ```
   typedef struct
   {
       int BillNumber, BillClass;
       float LastMeter, CurrentMeter;
       char name[128];
   } BillDatabase;
   ```

   This is easy, but not good, because the name can never be more than 128 chars.  Also, please don't EVER put the entire struct on one line.  I almost started hitting myself over the head with my saxophone.
2. The harder way out: learn to use `malloc()`, and manually allocate the name arrays.

Comment: "_Maybe this question would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com._" -- No. CR is for **working code**, not broken code.

Comment: Right on, @CoolGuy. Edited out from his post. Other than that, nice answer btw +1

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating any memory for your `name`s, so you're just writing into random places in memory. This is undefined behaviour.